# TL-WN722N not recognised = broken?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I just bought a TL-WN722N usb wifi-adapter, but it doesn't show up in the system. I can't find it with `sudo lsusb`, there is no additional network adapter listed in sudo `lshw -C network` and nothing changes in `sudo journalctl -fa` when I plug it in.

Can I assume that the device might be broken (it was used off Ebay, but proclaimed to be working by the dealer). I assued that it would be plug & play, since the driver and firmware are open-source and should be in the kernel.

Comment: Plug the adapter in another port and see what shows in `lsusb` It might be dead or be a different version that doesn't have the Atheros chipset

Comment: No other port works, I've also tried it on my Xubuntu laptop, but it also won't show. As far as I know, there is another version with a different chipset that requires a blob, but shouldn'it appear in the USB devices, regardless?

Comment: I think the Atheros shows as 0cf3:9271 device in lsusb and the version 3 shows as 2357:010c, if nothing changes in lsusb results, it is likely broken